# Error with PreviousPage Directive

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im using Webforms , C# , Vs 2013

I try to access one Form form another using PreviousPage.

So I add the following to the 2nd page:

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Survey.aspx" %>
```

As soon I add this code the following code is automatically generated :

```
  public new HousingSurvey.HousingSurvey PreviousPage {
            get {
                return ((HousingSurvey.HousingSurvey)(base.PreviousPage));
            }
        }
```

And I get

```
Error   31  The type name 'HousingSurvey' does not exist in the type 'HousingSurvey.HousingSurvey'
```

HousingSurvey Class is defined in the Survey.aspx

```
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Survey.aspx.cs" Inherits="HousingSurvey.HousingSurvey" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated method works as long, as the previous page really is of the said type.

If the previous page **can** be of another type, you will need to leave the generated method alone, and using your own method or property, with sanity checks. This covers the case when the previous page is not the one expected. I have this situation for example, when the user changes the language while on the target page.

Here's my code (in Target.aspx.cs):

```
/// <summary>
///     Gets the previous page, if it was an instance of the "MyPrevious.aspx" page.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>This access is used for the access to data from the "MyPrevious.aspx" page.</remarks>
/// <value>
///     The previous page, if it was an instance of the "MyPrevious.aspx" page, null otherwise.
/// </value>
private MyPrevious CheckedPreviousPage {
    get {
        if (base.PreviousPage != null) {
            if (base.PreviousPage is MyPrevious) {
                return PreviousPage;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's how to use the property (in Target.aspx.cs):

```
if ((CheckedPreviousPage != null) && (CheckedPreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack)) {
    //Cross page post, populating fields
    MyTextBox.Text = CheckedPreviousPage.SomeTextBox.Text;
}
```

This code explicitly uses the `base.PreviousPage` getter property and custom checks, avoiding the use of the generated method.